# Which Framework or CMS for Google-Video like site?

Tags: frameworks, content-management-system

I am working on a Web Project similar to Google-Video.

As for now, I want to start coding the site.

I know some PHP, HTML and MySQL.

I already have:

- Database built and ready (in MySQL)
- Links and Tags in the Database

The thing is, I don't want to code everything from hand.

As I've seen so far, with CMS it's not possible to use my own database. Or am I wrong?

And what Framework would you suggest me?

*Looking forward for your advice!*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start over, but use your existing DB design as your logical schema to be implemented in the CMS you eventually choose.
Go to http://cmsmatrix.org/ and compare Drupal, Joomla!, eZ Publish and TYPO3 for the best fit for your requirements.
Also, pay attention to the search engine features available with each one. e.g. eZ Publish eZ Find is based on Lucene.
In terms of functionality ( but excluding add management and your specific layout or graphic-design) you should be able to create a reasonable clone within a few hours using eZ. Here is one example http://untoldstories.eu/ezinfo/about